# The Inquisition

Tags: history

What was the reason of the Inquisition, who started it, and did it do what it was supposed to do?

Comment: Is this on-topic and not easily google-able?

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Inquisition) is the Wikipedia article on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the Spanish Inquisition this was done by King Ferdinand and Queen Isabella who were convinced by a friar to initiate it. It was obstensibly done to fight heresy but assumed they were fighting for more political authority versus the church's authority.